# Show exact value in contents in tooltips in jquery plot

Tags: jquery, plot, tooltip

I have Chart and i want to show exact data on tooltip.Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qbXDw/35/)

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url:"reports/graphfilter.php",
  data: {},
   async: true,
dataType: "json",
success: function( data ) {var forum = data.results;
var i, l,dest1 = [],dest2 = [],dest3 = [],dest4 = [],dest5=[],dest6=[],row;
 for(i = 0, l = forum.length; i < l; i++) { 
    row = forum[i];
    dest1.push([i, row.publish]);
    dest2.push([i, row.unpublish]);
    dest3.push([i, row.pending]);
    dest4.push([i,row.agent]);
}
var stack = 0, bars = true, lines = false, steps = false, points = false;
var options1 = {
    series: {stack: stack,
             lines: { show: lines, fill: false, steps: steps },
             bars: { show: bars, barWidth: 0.4 },
             points: { show: true}
             },
             grid: {
      hoverable: true //IMPORTANT! this is needed for tooltip to work
        },
  tooltip: true,
  tooltipOpts: {
  content: "%s : %y", 
  shifts: {
       x: -60,
       y: 25
        }
  },
        legend:{'position':'ne','show':true,'margin':[-3, -20],'backgroundOpacity':0.1, 'noColumns': 4, 'container': null},
            xaxis: {ticks: dest4 ,},

};
 $.plot($("#flot-example-2"),  [{data:dest3,bars:{ show: bars, barWidth: .5  },label:"Total Pending", color:"green"},{data:dest1,bars:{ show: bars, barWidth: .5 },label:"Total Published", color:"purple"}, {data:dest2,bars:{ show: bars, barWidth: .5 },label:"Total Unpublished", color:"blue", backgroundOpacity: 0.9} ], options1);
```

On tooltip it shows Yaxis value.On one bar i am having three values,If first one is 1 and 2nd is 3 and 3rd one is 0,it shows 4 for 3rd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content property takes a function as well as the string. For custom output, try using the function. That is how I was able to display the actual value in for a pie chart.

The github page is [here](https://github.com/krzysu/flot.tooltip).

A snippet of the code I used for the custom tooltip is as below

```
tooltip: true,
tooltipOpts: {
    content: function(label, x, y) {  return Cai.String.fmt('{0} - {1}% (value: {2})', label, x.toFixed(2), y[0][1]); }
}
```

To inspect the arguments in your case, just dump the arguments to the console (`console.log('args: ',arguments')`). It was how I got to know where the raw value is stored.